# Is it possible to manually set Work Item ID in Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: tfs-workitem

Is it possible to manually set Work Item IDs in Team Foundation Server 2010?

When I put the id field on the work item layout it's automatically set as readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is the identifier of the workitems and cannot be changed.

If you want to have a reference number (for e.g. another ticketing system), then add a new field.
If you want to start with a certain value, then create first n dummy work items to reach that number: http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/10/20/tfs-2010-work-item-seed-tfs-work-item-system.id-at.aspx